# Disable "Automatically retrieve data when form is opened" Option in InfoPath 2010

Tags: forms, performance, infopath

I have an InfoPath 2010 Form that I have built. It's main connection is to an .accdb on a network drive. I am trying to speed up the initial loading time (currently runs 35+ seconds), as the form was built for individuals to do data entry into an Access dB. I have removed all the secondary data connections I had that were populating drop down lists and added them into the local form. No improvement. One of the only other options I have seen is to disable "Automatically retrieve data when form is opened". As dumb as I feel right now, for the life of me I can't seem to find where this option is, let alone can be changed. I have checked in modify data connections, form properties, form options, and all I can find online are people saying to disable it, but not ***how*** to. Can anyone enlighten me as to how this can be achieved?

Comment: Just google "infopath automatically retrieve data when form is opened".  Second hit notes the wizard step with that option.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I saw and disabled for the few secondary data connections I had. although I don't see any option/way to limit the main connection. As after disabling the secondary updates, there was no change in initial load time for the form.